# NSLog messages while using Leaks

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode, memory-leaks

How do I see NSLog messages while using Leaks? It does not show the console output?

Comment: Can you make your question more clearer?

Comment: I mean when using Leaks Instrument, the NSLog statement output are not visible in Console. So how can I check the values . Hopw I am clear now. !!

Comment: Well, the Leaks Instrument should say you what and where is causing leak. Why do you still want a NSLog statement to write the output mentioning leaks to console ?

Comment: Mahesh..u did not seem to understand the question at all..Anyways, I have got the answer I was looking for from Harinder..U can see it below.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While using instruments, NSLog statements do not show in the Debugger Console. If you want to see your NSLog statements, you will need to load the system Console application (/Applications/Utilities/Console).

I hope it helps

Comment: Perfect Harinder..That's what I was looking for..Great !!